# Counting arrays in loop

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a loop...

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $staff[] = $rows['staff'];
        $a = array_count_values($staff);
        $b = count($a);
        echo"$b<br>";

    }
```

that output

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
5
```

on my research, it must be  and I wanted the result to be this way

```
3   (is equal to three 1's)
3   (is equal to three 2's)
2   (is equal to two 3)
1   (is equal to one 4)
2   (is equal to two 5's)
```

any help?

what I want is to get the number of same element in an array

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Bugs and dbaseman I edited my question

Comment: We don't have a [mcve] here. We don't know what is in each row's `staff` column and we don't have a clear declaration of how that data will relate to the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your concern, this should do the trick:

```
$staff = array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $staff[] = $rows['staff'];
}
$a = array_count_values($staff);
print_r($a);
```